# 422 (Unprocessable Entity) Ajax and Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

In his life, he only encountered an ajax 2 times and here again our paths intertwined with him and he gave me 422 errors. I googled and realized that 422 error is a validation error, but in what specific place the error, I just can not understand.

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $( "#form" ).submit(function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var message = $('#message').val();
        var img = $('#img').val();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{route('profile.store', ['id' => Auth::user()->id])}}",
            data: {message:message, img:img, user_id:user_id},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#textpost").html($(data).find("#textpost").html());
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my method

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $validator  = $this->validate($request,[
        'message' => 'required|max:1000',
        'img' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,gif|max:3000',
    ]);

    if($validator ) {
        $post = new Profile();
        $post->message = $request->message;
        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        if($request->file('img')) {
            $path = Storage::putFile('public', $request->file('img'));
            $url = Storage::url($path);
            $post->img = $url;
        }

        $post->save();
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And my form

```
<div class="card-header">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <form action="{{route('profile.store', ['id' => Auth::user()->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
                                    @csrf
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" cols="100" rows="4" placeholder="О чем думаешь?"></textarea>
                                    <input type="file" id="img" name="img" value="Прикрепить изображение" class="mt-2">
                                    <div class="text-right">
                                        {{--                                        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm mt-4">--}}
                                        <button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm mt-4">Отправить</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your Ajax call, because you are uploading text and file at the same time you can pass it through `FormData`. You were also missing

```
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
```

Here is the updated ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $( "#form" ).submit(function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData(this); //set formData to selected instance 
        var message = $('#message').val();
        var img = $('#img').val();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{route('profile.store', ['id' => Auth::user()->id])}}",
            data: formData, //pass to our Ajax data to send
            success: function (data) {
                $("#textpost").html($(data).find("#textpost").html());
            },
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Setting `processData` makes it so your FormData is not converted to a string. Setting `contentType` to false is used for forms that pass files, when false, no header will be added to the request, which is exactly what we want when submitting `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $validator  = $this->validate($request,[
        'message' => 'required|max:1000',
        'img' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif|max:3000',
    ]);
```

This portion of your code throws a validation errors exception which returns 422.

If you wish to handle validation on your own, try this logic instead:

```
$validator = validator($request->all(), [
'message' => 'required|max:1000',
        'img' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,gif|max:3000',
]);

if($validator->fails()) {
// return as appropriate
return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
}

// rest of your code
```